# Why site instruction returns 4 results?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search

I have some junk websites, each of which has thousands of junk posts. When I search on google using "site:example.com", it returns 4 results for all these websites. I'm curious why it returns exact 4 results, not 3, not 5. Is it google's warning message? But when I log in google search console, I can see google indexes thousands of posts.

Comment: I don't understand why you might think having exactly 4 results (as opposed to 3 or 5) would be a "warning message" from Google.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I think google might warn me "your website is of low quality" by returning this particular number of results.

Answer (score 1):

The number of results is the number of urls it has indexed on your site.  If the structure of those sites is the same, then maybe they happen to have similar pages indexed.

Comment: `site:` searches don't show all the indexed content from a site.  Google has purposefully made them less accurate to prevent SEO analysis using them.  The order of results is no longer very meaningful, the reported number of results is an estimate, and not everything is shown.